# how to destructively mutate the Object in a function

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to get the function destructivelyDeleteEmployeeByKey(employee, key) to return employee without the deleted key/value pair that would modify the original employee

this is what itsays in the test.js file

```
describe('destructivelyDeleteFromEmployeeByKey(employee, key)', function () {
it('returns employee without the deleted key/value pair', function () {
  let newEmployee = destructivelyDeleteFromEmployeeByKey(employee, 'name');

  expect(newEmployee['name']).to.equal(undefined);
});

it('modifies the original employee', function () {
  let newEmployee = destructivelyDeleteFromEmployeeByKey(employee, 'name');

  expect(employee['name']).to.equal(undefined);
  expect(employee).to.equal(newEmployee);
});
```

});

how do I write this function?

Comment: Basically same [as your other function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72649613) but don't clone the object - work with it directly.

Comment: Where does `employee` come from in your test?

Answer (score 0):

you should use the [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) opetator:

```
var person = {
  firstName:"John",
  lastName:"Doe",
  age:50,
  eyeColor:"blue"
};

delete person.age;  
OR
delete person["age"];
```

in you case you can delete based on the parameter you are passing

Answer (score 0):

Did you meeam something like that? I think it should work

```
const destructivelyDeleteFromEmployeeByKey = (employee, key) => {
   delete employee[key]
   return employee
}
```

Comment: thanks so much.. its obvious to me now lol